# 1 component off to the right in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Problem of the gui screen. Login component off to the side.
[image]

Resolution of the gui screen. Had to make jtextfield's comp width 2 for some reason.
[image]

I have a little thing thing that I have no idea what's been causing it... My login button is off to the right side. I know that it's probably caused by the jtextfields being so big and then positioning the 3rd cell next to it but is there any way to fix it? Or is it the `JCheckBox` somehow conflicting with the 3rd row components because it is too small? I need the login button to somehow move to the right more but I don't think it's possible because the 2nd x cell has 2 `JTextField` components that take up all the space.

```
        addComp(pLogin, new JLabel("Name: "), 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_END);
    addComp(pLogin, new JLabel("Password: "), 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_END);

    //these are going to be formatted fields. Remember johnny remove the new jtextfield soon
    addComp(pLogin, new JTextField(15), 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);
    addComp(pLogin, new JTextField(15), 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);

    addComp(pLogin, remember_User, 0, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_END);
    addComp(pLogin, new JLabel("Remember me"), 1, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);
    addComp(pLogin, login, 2, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp, int xPos, int yPos, int compWidth, int compHeight, int place) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = xPos;
        gbc.gridy = yPos;
        gbc.gridwidth = compWidth;
        gbc.gridheight = compHeight;
        gbc.anchor = place;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }
```

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: OK thank you I will do that when I get home sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change width of both text fields to 2 rather than 1

```
addComp(pLogin, new JTextField(15), 1, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);
addComp(pLogin, new JTextField(15), 1, 1, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START);
```

Comment: Thanks this actually worked but how did work? I'm not sure how changing the width makes the login button able to go to it's actual position?

Comment: You have 3 columns in the bottom row (checkbox, label, button) but 2 columns in the first and second row (label and textfield). so we let the textfield occupy 2 columns